# EZSwipeController existing storyboard implementation

Tags: ios, swift, ezswipecontroller

So I've just discovered the [cocoa controls website](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) where I've found [this control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ezswipecontroller) I would like to use.

I had a read through the [documentation](https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwipeController) on github however it is a bit vague for me due to my level of knowledge. I want to apply this control to two viewControllers that I already have but I don't understand where to place `presentViewController(EZSwipeController(), animated: true, completion: nil)` and which segue connections should be created on the storyboard. Also can I leave my viewControllers embedded in the navigation controller or will this affect the functionality.

Thanks,
Steve